# Anaconda Navigator installing old version of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I've been trying to find a way to install Tensorflow v1.0.0 in anaconda but there is only v1.2.1 and v1.1.0 in the options.

I've tried to use pip to install wheel packages but resulted in 'could not find a version that satisfies the requirement' error.

Any suggestions on how I can install v1.0.0?

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm using windows 10 64 bit, no gpu, 8gb ram, and i3-2120

Answer (score 4):

TensorFlow 1.0.0 for Windows is only compiled for Python 3.5.  If you have a recent install of Anaconda (4.3.0 or higher), you are likely on Python 3.6.  To get specifically 1.0.0 you need to the following Conda commands to create a Python 3.5 environment named "tensorflow" with Jupyter Notebooks, and then install TensorFlow 1.0.0

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5 jupyter -y
conda install --name tensorflow tensorflow=1.0.0 --channel conda-forge -y
```

This is going to take a good amount of time to install.  After it finishes, you can swap to the environment and fire up a Jupyter Notebook using:

```
activate tensorflow
jupyter notebook
```